# Symfony YAML include file

Tags: symfony, yaml

How can I split my security.yml into multiple files?

I know about the imports statement, but I need to import the role_hierarchy.

For example

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:       
            //IMPORT FROM USER.YML
        ROLE_SELLER:
            //IMPORT FROM ANOTHER SELLER.YML
        ROLE_ADMIN:       
           //IMPORT FROM ADMIN.YML
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

I need this because I want to define the roles for sonata admin's, and I don't want to store them in the database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the roles as config parameters:

```
// user_roles.yml
parameters:
    seller_roles: [ROLE_A, ROLE_B, ROLE_C]
```

And use them in the security config:

```
// security.yml
imports:
    - { resource: user_roles.yml }

security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SELLER: %seller_roles%
```